# Incorrect output from Service Fabric build in Azure DevOps

Tags: build, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines

Currently, I am creating an Azure DevOps build for my service fabric application. On my local machine the build, package and publish steps work like expected.

But when I run the template Azure service fabric build on Azure DevOps the output generated is incorrect. The service package does not contain my `.exe` in the code folder instead the folder contains the root folder of my `.sfproj`.

In the build and package step of the `.sfproj` output I can see the service getting build.

The current build looks like this:
- Use NuGet
- NuGet restore
- Build .sln
- Build .sfproj
- copy files pdbs
- Delete files *.pdbs
- Update service fabric manifest
- Copy build files
- Publish artifact

The things I already tried:
- Implement the service fabric template build on DevOps.
- Tried following a few tutorials on the internet.
- Tried to make sense of what is happening and how it is happening.
- Tried running a local PowerShell build (maybe something was wrong with my files), this build succeeded with the correct output.

The output I expect from the build:

```
>D:\TEMP\MYAPPLICATIONTYPE
>>ApplicationManifest.xml
>>>MyServiceManifest
>>>>ServiceManifest.xml  
>>>MyCode  
>>>> - MyServiceHost.exe   
>>>MyConfig  
>>>> - Settings.xml  
>>>MyData  
>>>> - init.dat'
```

The output I get from the build:

```
>D:\TEMP\MYAPPLICATIONTYPE
>>ApplicationManifest.xml
>>>MyServiceManifest
>>>>ServiceManifest.xml  
>>>MyCode  
>>>> - ApplicationPackageRoot  
    - ApplicationParameters  
    - obj  
   - PublishProfiles  
   - Scripts  
    - Packages.config  
    - ServiceFabricApplication.sfproj  
    - ServiceFabricApplication.sfproj.log   
>>>MyConfig  
>>>> - Settings.xml  
>>>MyData  
>>>> - init.dat'
```

In the release step the following error occurs that does not occur in a local publish:

```
`2019-04-08T14:31:51.9203463Z Service fabric SDK version: 2.4.164.9494.
2019-04-08T14:31:52.4143574Z ##[debug]INPUT_USEDIFFPACKAGE: 'false'
2019-04-08T14:31:52.5363270Z ##[debug]MAILPROCESSINGSERVICE_INSTANCECOUNT (empty)
2019-04-08T14:31:52.5383524Z ##[debug]INPUT_OVERWRITEBEHAVIOR: 'SameAppTypeAndVersion'
2019-04-08T14:31:53.5679860Z ##[debug]Join-Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\fabric\fabric.code" "ServiceFabricServiceModel.xsd"
2019-04-08T14:31:53.5726035Z ##[debug]C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\fabric\fabric.code\ServiceFabricServiceModel.xsd
2019-04-08T14:31:53.5738046Z ##[debug]Length: 94
2019-04-08T14:31:53.5757439Z ##[debug]
2019-04-08T14:31:53.5780120Z ##[debug]Test-Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\fabric\fabric.code\ServiceFabricServiceModel.xsd"
2019-04-08T14:31:53.5819217Z ##[debug]True
2019-04-08T14:31:53.5832941Z ##[debug]
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9628794Z ##[debug]System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.FabricImageBuilderValidationException: Exception while parsing XML file: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\TestApplicationPackage_31174153637\r5wofi1j.xyh\applicationpackage\ApplicationManifest.xml
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9641825Z ##[debug]FileName: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\TestApplicationPackage_31174153637\r5wofi1j.xyh\applicationpackage\ApplicationManifest.xml ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 254). ---> System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: The 'ManifestId' attribute is not declared.
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9655413Z ##[debug]   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(XmlSchemaValidationException e, XmlSeverityType severity)
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9668097Z ##[debug]   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(String code, String arg)
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9680818Z ##[debug]   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ValidateAttribute(String lName, String ns, XmlValueGetter attributeValueGetter, String attributeStringValue, XmlSchemaInfo schemaInfo)
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9694803Z ##[debug]   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ValidateAttributes()
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9707640Z ##[debug]   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessElementEvent()
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9846731Z ##[debug]   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9860420Z ##[debug]   at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9876589Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read395_ApplicationManifest()
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9889383Z ##[debug]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9903452Z ##[debug]   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9919035Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ImageBuilderUtility.ReadXml[T](String fileName, XmlReader reader)
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9936054Z ##[debug]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9945480Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ImageBuilderUtility.TraceAndThrowValidationErrorWithFileName(Exception innerException, String type, String fileName, String format, Object[] args)
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9958172Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ImageBuilderUtility.ReadXml[T](String fileName, XmlReader reader)
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9971320Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ImageBuilderUtility.ReadXml[T](String fileName, XmlReaderSettings validatingXmlReaderSettings)
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9984222Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ApplicationProvisionOperation.<ParseApplicationPackageAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
2019-04-08T14:31:55.9996678Z ##[debug]--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-04-08T14:31:56.0009376Z ##[debug]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
2019-04-08T14:31:56.0022409Z ##[debug]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2019-04-08T14:31:56.0035985Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ApplicationProvisionOperation.<ProvisionApplicationAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
2019-04-08T14:31:57.8717259Z ##[debug]SYSTEM_JOBID: '7541fd7f-879e-4baf-a7a6-9e527906c514'
2019-04-08T14:31:58.3025935Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[telemetry.publish area=TaskHub;feature=ServiceFabricDeploy]{"OperationId":"TestApplicationPackage","ExceptionData":"System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.FabricImageBuilderValidationException;System.InvalidOperationException;System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException;|D:\\a\\_tasks\\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\\1.7.31\\ServiceFabricSDK\\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1|243","JobId":"7541fd7f-879e-4baf-a7a6-9e527906c514","SDKVersion":"2.4.164.9494"}
2019-04-08T14:31:58.8521847Z ##[debug]Leaving D:\a\_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.7.31\deploy.ps1.
2019-04-08T14:31:58.8569063Z ##[debug]Caught exception from task script.
2019-04-08T14:31:58.8613132Z ##[debug]Error record:
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9458146Z ##[debug]Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage : Exception while parsing XML file: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\TestApplicationPackage_31174153637\r5wofi1j.xyh\applicationpackage\ApplicationManifest.xml
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9475003Z ##[debug]FileName: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\TestApplicationPackage_31174153637\r5wofi1j.xyh\applicationpackage\ApplicationManifest.xml
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9487449Z ##[debug]At D:\a\_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.7.31\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1:243 char:46
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9501612Z ##[debug]+ ... tionSuccess = (Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage $AppPkgPathToUse)
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9516184Z ##[debug]+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9544781Z ##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Test-ServiceFabricApplica    tionPackage], FabricImageBuilderValidationException
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9559184Z ##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestApplicationPackageErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceF    abric.Powershell.TestApplicationPackage
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9575586Z ##[debug] 
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9596675Z ##[debug]Script stack trace:
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9642005Z ##[debug]at Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication, D:\a\_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.7.31\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1: line 243
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9655696Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, D:\a\_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.7.31\deploy.ps1: line 194
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9674225Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9687438Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 22
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9713344Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 18
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9723271Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9745709Z ##[debug]Exception:
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9793977Z ##[debug]System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.FabricImageBuilderValidationException: Exception while parsing XML file: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\TestApplicationPackage_31174153637\r5wofi1j.xyh\applicationpackage\ApplicationManifest.xml
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9805388Z ##[debug]FileName: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\TestApplicationPackage_31174153637\r5wofi1j.xyh\applicationpackage\ApplicationManifest.xml ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 254). ---> System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: The 'ManifestId' attribute is not declared.
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9818107Z ##[debug]   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(XmlSchemaValidationException e, XmlSeverityType severity)
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9829274Z ##[debug]   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(String code, String arg)
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9840639Z ##[debug]   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.ValidateAttribute(String lName, String ns, XmlValueGetter attributeValueGetter, String attributeStringValue, XmlSchemaInfo schemaInfo)
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9851940Z ##[debug]   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ValidateAttributes()
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9863424Z ##[debug]   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessElementEvent()
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9877769Z ##[debug]   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9891850Z ##[debug]   at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9906079Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read395_ApplicationManifest()
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9917176Z ##[debug]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9928302Z ##[debug]   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9939501Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ImageBuilderUtility.ReadXml[T](String fileName, XmlReader reader)
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9950819Z ##[debug]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9962116Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ImageBuilderUtility.TraceAndThrowValidationErrorWithFileName(Exception innerException, String type, String fileName, String format, Object[] args)
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9973510Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ImageBuilderUtility.ReadXml[T](String fileName, XmlReader reader)
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9984837Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ImageBuilderUtility.ReadXml[T](String fileName, XmlReaderSettings validatingXmlReaderSettings)
2019-04-08T14:31:58.9998358Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ApplicationProvisionOperation.<ParseApplicationPackageAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
2019-04-08T14:31:59.0007662Z ##[debug]--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2019-04-08T14:31:59.0020745Z ##[debug]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
2019-04-08T14:31:59.0032029Z ##[debug]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2019-04-08T14:31:59.0045270Z ##[debug]   at System.Fabric.Management.ImageBuilder.ApplicationProvisionOperation.<ProvisionApplicationAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
2019-04-08T14:31:59.0363118Z ##[error]Exception while parsing XML file: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\TestApplicationPackage_31174153637\r5wofi1j.xyh\applicationpackage\ApplicationManifest.xml
FileName: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\TestApplicationPackage_31174153637\r5wofi1j.xyh\applicationpackage\ApplicationManifest.xml
2019-04-08T14:31:59.0371868Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]Exception while parsing XML file: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\TestApplicationPackage_31174153637\r5wofi1j.xyh\applicationpackage\ApplicationManifest.xml%0D%0AFileName: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\TestApplicationPackage_31174153637\r5wofi1j.xyh\applicationpackage\ApplicationManifest.xml
2019-04-08T14:31:59.0373492Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]`
```

Comment: What `MSBuild Arguments` do you use to build `.sfproj` and `.sln`?

Comment: For the `.sln` the following arguments are used: `/p:RunInBuild=true`
For the `.sfproj` the following arguments are used: 
`/t:Package /p:PackageLocation=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\Application\applicationpackage`

Answer (score 0):

If you have `BuildPlatform` set to `Any CPU` or `x32` change it to `x64` on Azure DevOps for both `.sln` and `.sfproj` and it should work.

Comment: I Cannot change the `.sln` to x64 because it contains multiple `.csproj` that need to be `AnyCPU`. Do I need to create a separate build specifically for the Service Fabric Application?

Comment: No you don't need to create a separate build. If you can't change `.sln` build to `x64` change only `.sfproj` build.

Comment: The `.sfproj` has dependencies in the rest of the solution, this makes it hard to just change the `.sfproj` I am currently trying to get this setup but I keep getting error after error at the moment. When I get a successful build ill post back here.

Comment: You have to build it in 64 bits otherwise it wont work, and you will be gettig weird errors like these.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the build issue is kind of fixed.

It was impossible to rewrite the whole solution to x64 or build the service against x64. The thing I did was the following:

1. Build the `.sfproj`
2. Copy the project artifacts to the staging dir.
3. Delete all the items from the `application/code` folder in the staged artifact.
4. Build the service separate from the '.sfproj'.
5. Copy the service build output into the `.sfproj` code package.

Next, for the release issues, the problem was that the other `.csproj` used the `hosted` agent. A `.sfproj` for some reason needs the `hosted vs2017` agent. By just adding a second agent phase that uses this agent fixes the release.

I hope that this can help people that are running into the same issues as me.